# jqGrid v4.0 Pager not working when using local datatype

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Im using jqGrid v4 to display some local data.  Ive tried to follow the simple example @ http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGrid.htm.  My results are that the pager elements are correct but they are disabled.  I've attached my code if anyone can help point out where I may be going wrong.  Any help appreciated.
Thanks

```
  var myData = [
      {   id:'1',   name:'a', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'2',   name:'b', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'3',   name:'c', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'4',   name:'d', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'5',   name:'e', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'6',   name:'f', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'7',   name:'g', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'8',   name:'h', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'9',   name:'i', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'10',  name:'j', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},        
      {   id:'11',  name:'k', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'12',  name:'l', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'13',  name:'m', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'},
      {   id:'14',  name:'n', dob:'2000-08-26',address:'here',telNo:'2587456'}                     
  ];
  $("#resultGrid").jqGrid({       
datatype: "local",
    data: myData,   
autowidth:true,
colNames:['ID','Name', 'DOB', 'Address','Telephone Number'],      
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', sorttype:"text"},
    {name:'name',index:'name',  sorttype:"text"},
    {name:'dob',index:'dob', sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
    {name:'address',index:'address', sorttype:"text"},
    {name:'telNo',index:'telNo', align:"right",sortable:false}              
],
    rowNum:10,
            rowList:[5,10,20],
            pager: '#pager',
            gridview:true,
            rownumbers:true,                
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            caption:'Search Results',
            height: '100%'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. How you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user746980.htm) the pager (go to the next page or to the last page) is not deacticated. You should compare exactly your code with my demo to find where is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but as far as I can see the only difference is the version number.  Im trying to use 4.0, where as the demo is using 3.8.2, have the methods for paging a local data array changed at all?

Comment: @user746980: I used jqGrid 4.0 in the demo. You can see if you open the file http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.0.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js used.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure in your server.php,
when you query, at the end you set the limits and sorting:

```sql
ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit
```

The first one, makes your table sortable(ORDER BY),
and the second one, using limits eq 0-5, 5-10, makes your grid move within set of records!